# Relation between two join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have the following tables: `Department`, `Section`, `Employee`,`Manager`, and `Position`. The relations between the tables are as follows:

- Each Department contains many sections
- Each Department contains many positions and  each position might  be shared with  different departments
- Each department section has a manager
- Each manager might has different positions, for instance,  **Urology Department Chairman** is a position as manager, and as an employee he is  a **Urology Consultant**. As an employee, he has two  positions.

[image]

As you can see from  the image above

- `DepartmentSections` is a Join table between Departments and Sections
- `DepartmentPositions` is a Join table  between Departments and Positions

My problem now, How I should configure Managers? I am thinking of making two relations, first between the Manager and `DepartmentSections` and between the Manager and `DepartmentPositions`, the problem here is that I will get two `DepartmentId`  fields in the table `Manager`.

Is there any mistake in my analysis? how to  build this model in order to  avoid 2 DepartmentId in the table Managers?

Comment: You just need to add primary key in `DepartmentPositions` and `DepartmentSections` and then use them in `Managers` ;).

Comment: Note that, use single names for your entities instead plurals (`Manager` instead `Managers`) - And I can't see any reason to have `DepartmentSections` table just use `DepartmentId` in `Sections` may handles your need - HTH ;)

Comment: @shA.t  I am using the following naming convention since Table Managers is a set of records that belongs to different details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts on your post. It is not an answer (too long to comment) but might help a bit.

> Each Department contains many sections

From this I guess that you don't need the lookup table `DepartmentSections` since this sentence describes one-to-many and not many-to-many relationship. You could add the `DepartmentId` in the `Sections` table.

> Each department section has a manager

So you could add the `ManagerId` to `Sections` table.

Now for positions and managers, If I understood correctly, I would add the `ManagerId` to `DepartmentPositions`.

Comment: I agree with your regarding putting the DepartmentID inside Sections table since there is no meaning to share a section with different departments, but How I will ensure from database structure that the DepartmentID  in Sections is the same as the one in the DepartmentPositions? making 3-anry relation between Departments and Positions and Sections is a night mare for our Instructor ( its not allow to use such relation)

Comment: You don't have to do anything. `DepartmentId` in `Section` table is a foreign key to `Department` table. Also `DepartmentId` in `DepartmentPosition` is a foreign key to `Department` table.